# Automated task emails not sending - SPD 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a simple leave request workflow going, and am using the "Assign a task" action. I have a separate group of approvers, and have the tasks assigned to that group.

In the email settings I have the email set to the default format, and this email should be sent to the approvers group mentioned above.

This works fine when I (site owner with full control) kick off the workflow. However, when others with different levels of access submit a task, then the email will either: not send at all, not send to all the necessary approvers (4 people), or send in a totally different format than I have set in SPD.

In searching for a solution I found that I may need to go into advanced list settings and have Email notification upon task assignment set to **yes**. After doing that the emails are sent in a different format than what I have setup in the SPD workflow (not preferred). Is this necessary for the SP designer workflow I am using?

Here is the workflow for reference-

[image: workflow]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add an **App Step** to your Workflow and put the **Assign a task** activity inside that **App Step**? This way this actvity will be executed with elevated permissions.

If the App Step option is disabled in your Sharepoint Designer, you will need to make some configuration in your site collection.

**Allow Workflow to use app permission**

- In site settings, open Manage site features
- Activate the Workflows can use app permissions

**Grant permission to a Sharepoint 2013 workflow**

- In site settings, open Site app permissions
- Next to the item named Workflow, copy the client section of the App Identifier. It's the identifier between the last "|" and the "@" sign.

For example : i:0i.t|ms.sp.ext|**4397ebb6-95a9-4ba2-9340-4a95dc700d54**@332cfbaa-d01c-4765-b195-f004ea3231a2

**Open the Grant permission to an app page**

there is no link to that page on the Site Settings. So you need to write the URL manually in your browser.

http://{your_host_name}/{path_to_your_site_collection}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx

- Paste the client id in the **App Id** field and then click the **Lookup** button
- In the **Permission Request XML** field, paste the following XML code :

  <AppPermissionRequests>
      <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
- Click the **Create** button.
- On the next screen, click the **Trust It** button.

After you made this configuration, the **App Step** option, will be available in your Sharepoint Designer. You will probably need to refresh or close and reopen SP Designer.

Hope this help!